# how to use multiple RAM chips with different timings and voltages

Tags: memory, computer-building, voltage, memory-timings

Last thanksgiving, I built a computer using [this RAM](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231278).  I have decided to upgrade to 8GB, so I just bought [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820104339).

As you can see, the 2 kits have different timings, voltages, and CLs.  Is it possible use them together, either as is or by overclocking one somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use them how, at all or as dual-channel?

You *can* use them together in general because the faster one will simply be slowed down to match the speed of the slower one.

As for dual-channel, you should be able to do it as long as you keep each matched pair in a separate channel (refer to your motherboard manual for slot-channel assignments).

Comment: *"As for dual-channel, you should be able to do it as long as you keep each matched pair in a separate channel"* - this is backwards.  For *dual channel*, a matched pair of modules must be installed in *two* different channels so that memory operations can be performed in parallel.  If installed in the same channel as you wrote, then the mismatched modules in the other channel will force single-channel operations.  Run a memory tester like **Memtest86+** which will report the memory configuration plus a whole lot more.

Comment: Yes, MemTest and the BIOS POST should indicate whether it is working or not. As for the channels, I think it’s a matter of terminology. By “channel”, I mean pair of slots. For example, if the board has two black and two blue slots, (on most boards), you should put the modules from the same pair in the same color slots. I guess it makes sense that the paired slots would use different channels, but (1) what would be the correct terminology for the pair of slots then? and (2) it would imply that the different modules are being mixed and thus the faster ones slowed down to match the slower ones.

Comment: *"By “channel”, I mean pair of slots"* - That's not a reliable definition.  What if there are six sockets?  What about "tri-channel"? "Channel" is typically defined as a data path.  Different motherboards color-code these channels in their own fashion.  The mobos I've used (mostly Asus) have one color for each memory channel, so dual channel requires a matching module in each color. (1) Adjacent memory sockets typically correspond to the same memory *bank*. (2) Using mixed modules will always result in the slowest speed, but it's slow dual channel or slower single channel.

Comment: BTW wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture) seems to make a similar error in the photo caption, (mis)stating that modules should go in sockets of the same color, which corresponds to the same channel.  I assert that matched modules should go in the same bank for dual channel, since that puts a module in each channel.  You have to use *two* channels (in one bank) to achieve *dual* channel.  The Wikipedia caption is incorrect.

Comment: *By “channel”, I mean pair of slots—That's not a reliable definition. What if there are six sockets?*   You know what I mean; pair, triplet, whatever. Yes, bank is a good term, I have seen it used in some motherboard manuals.     *> The Wikipedia caption is incorrect.*   Really? Are you sure it’s wrong for the NF4? Unfortunately there is no standard for referring to multi-channel architecture which is reflected in the fact that motherboards implement it differently. My point was that the OP can achieve dual-channel mode by matching their RAM modules correctly as required by their motherboard.

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for here.  Is the correct solution to place the matching chips in the same color slots, or in opposit color slots?  Also, is there any configuration that needs to be done in the BIOS or anything?

Comment: Also, is there no issue with the non=matching voltages?\

Comment: @ewok, configuring multi-channel configuration depends on your motherboard which you haven’t specified. As for voltage, it’s a only 0.05V difference. Your motherboard likely supports either, but again, you’ll have to specify it.

Comment: [Gigabyte GA-970A-D3](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4306#ov).  It does support either voltage (I've used both).  The questions are 1) will the board use both kits at the same time supplying different voltages where necessary? and 2) is it likely that a dual channel setup will work plug-and-play or is there going to be some configuration?

Comment: @ewok, how do you know it will support 1.6V+? The [specs page](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4306#sp) clearly says it is only rated for 1.5V. Using 1.6V+ modules may work for now since the motherboard is overclocking to support them, but it is likely that you will start having problems eventually and be back here asking a question about random reboots and such. As for configuration, what does [the manual](http://download.gigabyte.ru/manual/mb_manual_ga-970a-d3_v.1.2_e.pdf) say?

Comment: @Synetech Are you sure it doesn't support 1.65V?  The [memory support list](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Memory/memory_ga-970a-d3.pdf) lists a number of 1.65V chips, such as the [Kingston KHX1600C9D3K3/12GX](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820104127&name=Desktop-Memory), which is very similar to the RAM I purchased.

Comment: That said, even when I had the chips that came in the Newegg combo, I did notice some random reboots, so maybe I should be using 1.5V chips

Comment: @ewok, The specs page only mentions 1.5V. I don’t see any mention of voltage in that list; I assume you looked up some of the models. (I suppose that there *could* be otherwise identical sticks with different voltages that use the same model number. Also, I’m *fairly* sure that the voltage indicated on product pages is the actual, operating voltage, not the maximum it can take.) Either way, I would recommend [asking Gigabyte](http://www.gigabyte.us/about-gigabyte/contact-us.aspx) since there is enough inconsistency and confusion that they would (supposedly) be the only ones to know for sure.